# Can't "sudo" anything. Any command returns a help message

Tags: 16.04, sudo

After a today updating an Ubuntu 16.04.3 system I can't run any command with sudo  as from non-privileged user and the same from a root. Every "sudo" call only returns a help message.

```
[21:22:06]
[svarog@svarog-PC~]$sudo -s
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user] [VAR=value]
            [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user] file ...
[21:37:39]
[root@svarog-PC/etc/sudoers.d]#sudo -i -u svarog
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user] [VAR=value]
            [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user] file ...

[21:41:35]
[root@svarog-PC/etc/sudoers.d]#uname -oiros
Linux 4.10.0-41-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux
[21:42:32]
[root@svarog-PC/etc/sudoers.d]#cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"


[21:43:43]
[root@svarog-PC/etc/sudoers.d]#dpkg -l | grep sudo | grep ii
ii  gksu                                                 2.0.2-9ubuntu1                                          amd64        graphical front-end to su and sudo
ii  gnome-sudoku                                         1:3.18.4-0ubuntu2                                       amd64        Sudoku puzzle game for GNOME
ii  libgksu2-0                                           2.0.13~pre1-6ubuntu8                                    amd64        library providing su and sudo functionality
ii  sudo                                                 1.8.16-0ubuntu1.5                                       amd64        Provide limited super user privileges to specific users
```

No broken packets, no unconfigured packets, no strange log errors in syslog. SUDO package is re-installed. Nothing helps. Please, can anyone help?

SU command works well. SUDOERS file looks normal.

Comment: This really intrigues me. No weird characters in the way in your `sudo -s` command? What does `which sudo` return?

Comment: sudo needs to be followed by a command.

Comment: All as I posted above - just a help message. No any other warnings.

Comment: @ravery

> sudo needs to be followed by a command.

It's not need a command to switch to other user with an "-s" key.

Comment: @mattias `

[21:47:54]
[root@svarog-PC/etc/sudoers.d]#which sudo
/usr/bin/sudo
[22:06:36]
[root@svarog-PC/etc/sudoers.d]#whereis sudo
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/lib/sudo /usr/share/man/man8/sudo.8.gz
`

Comment: @Vitalii -- "usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user] [VAR=value]  [-i|-s] [<command>]". sudo does not switch users, it runs a command as another user

Comment: @ravery How does I do this at my other PC then?
`[22:08:18]
root@ThinkPad/usr/lib/sudo]#exit
[22:08:19]
[vitalii@ThinkPad~]$sudo -s
[sudo] пароль до vitalii: 
[22:08:27]
[root@ThinkPad/home/vitalii]#`

Comment: @ravery technically you're right of course, it's runs a shell from a current user.

Comment: Run `alias`. See if there's an alias for `sudo`. Also, try `set | grep sudo` to see if there's anything there.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex You're right! Thank you a lot! There was an alias in a .bashrc files of a both users "svarog" and "root".  Seems like during an update there was added a line "sudo -H" and it was inserted between two other aliases and without a line break. It's became a one line with another alias and an **alias** command has printed it like an **alias sudo='sudo -Halias'** Now an issue is fixed! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `alias`. See if there's an alias for `sudo`. Also, try `set | grep sudo` to see if there's anything there.

If you find anything, look in `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` for the alias or function overriding `sudo`.